# Find an object in an array, which string field includes a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of objects (comments added by users):

```
const myArray = [
  {
    "text": "Hello",
    "id": "11",
    "$type": "Comment"
  },
  {
    "text": "Date of birth: 01-01-2022",
    "id": "22",
    "$type": "Comment"
  },
  {
    "text": "lalala",
    "id": "33",
    "$type": "Comment"
  }
];
```

My goal is:

1. find object, which string field `text` includes a phrase `Date of birth`
2. find value of `id` field in this object

I tried this:

```
let dateOfBirthComment = myArray.find(element => element.text.includes('Date of birth'));

let dateOfBirthCommentId = dateOfBirthComment.id;

console.log(dateOfBirthCommentId);
```

When executing code above I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes')
```

Unfortunately, I can't use this:

```
let dateOfBirthComment = array.find(element => element.text === 'Date of birth: 01-01-2022');
```

Because date can be absolutely random in different cases.

Solution seems to be easy, but I'm quite new in JS and I'm really stuck. Could you please help me?

Comment: That means `text` is `null` in some of those objects. Either filter those beforehand or use [Optional chaining](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Your *provided* code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/uhev8aqL/   - it fails if your have a missing/null text value *before* the one that matches.

Comment: use `Optional chaining(?.)`. No error show, if some object doesn't have text